SSIS - How to read data's modified date in the Control flow or Data flow?
I am creating SSIS package.
I need to get modified date of data files.
So far, In the Data flow. I have 'Derived Column Transformation' I need to enter 'modified date' of data files. So I am thinking that initialize variable called 'User::modifiedDate' then extract modified date from files and then assign that values to variable 'User::modifiedDate'. Is this right approach?
Since I have no experience for SSIS, I want to know how to get modified date and then assign...
For example, the first file shows a "Date modified" in Windows Explorer of "2024-02-22 17:05" and I would like to have that available in my Data Flow to store in the OLE DB Destination



It would be better to use a 'Foreach Loop Container' in the Control Flow based on your scenario.


To achieve this, you can follow these steps:

Initialize Variable: Create a variable named User::ModifiedDate (DateTime) and a variable named User::FilePath (String).

Loop Through Folder: With Foreach Loop Container, you can iterate through all the files in selected folder.




Assign FilePath to variable: Assign your FilePath variable under "Variable Mapping" to retrieve the current file path being looped through.



Script Task: Assign your variable as illustrated in the image below, then proceed to "Edit Script".



Edit Script: The following script is referring to @SteveFord's answer.

public void Main()
{
    System.IO.FileInfo file =
          new System.IO.FileInfo(Dts.Variables["User::FilePath"].Value.ToString());

    if (file.Exists)
    {
        Dts.Variables["User::ModifiedDate"].Value = file.LastWriteTime;
    }
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}


Utilize your ModifiedDate: You will now be able to utilize your ModifiedDate variable within your data flow for any necessary processing.


Thanks for providing your solution. I am following yours step by step. Is that okay if I contact you if I stuck? I really want to solve the problem as this is my first step at work.

date is just set with Default date as 1899-12-30 00:00:00.000

Hi @MINYOUNGCHOE, the "Default date" you mention here is referring to ModifiedDate variable's default value? If yes, any value will do, since the value will be override by the file.LastWriteTime. You can place a break point at the Script to debug if needed.

I was passing only filename without file path, this is why it could not load data properly.
